# Windows 7 Reconfigure Dynamic Disk which uses 2 physical disks

Tags: windows, hard-drive, audio, format

I've inherited a Windows 7 machine and am having some storage management issues.  I'm not too much of Windows expert so hoping for some help.  My computer is setup with having a 56GB C drive and a separate 500GB E drive. Windows OS is installed and boots from C drive, and E drive is just used as storage at this time.  I have somethings on the C drive I would like to keep and not delete, but anything on E drive can be wiped.  I've used up pretty much all the space on the C drive, and installing new programs and things cannot be done (even if I select E drive).  It also appears that the 2 drives are linked as dynamic disk and cannot be easily separated.

What I would like to do is one of the following:  Either make E drive a separate bootable drive to install new programs and data, or to someone be able to install things and run them from E drive while my OS runs on C drive.  I think one of the first steps I will need to do is detach the drives from each other and the dynamic disk properties.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what would be the best way to move forward?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N33Xv.jpg)

Comment: The only way you can convert a dynamic disk back to a regular disk is by completely wiping the data. In this case, what you may want to do is remove the partition from E, then increase the length of the C partition to span both drives, merging them basically. The only downside is that if either disk breaks, you loose all data.

Comment: But it has been a long time ago since I worked with dynamic disks. It may actually require you to delete the partitions and create a new spanned volume in the empty space to accomplish the goal. Once that partition exists, you could make it larger. So the first step you may need to do is using something like AIOMEI partition manager and move the partition from C to E. You can then also increase its size. But I bet C is an SSD and E is a slow drive. But with C emptied, and spare room on E, you could create that striped multispanning partition.

Comment: That said, I think what you want to do instead is move individual folders from C to E, and use MKLINK to create mount points in the original location pointing to the E drive. You can effectively move the entire program files folder that way, but keep in mind, this has to be done outside of windows.

Comment: Thanks LPChip, how would I go about removing the partition from E?  I wasn't able to find how to actually do that.  And also using MKLINK, is this something I can do from boot menu using console before booting Windows OS?

Comment: mklink is a utility that you can run inside a command prompt run as administrator. If you run windows setup, you can hit shift-f10 to get into a command prompt, or if you press shift then click restart, you will boot into recovery mode where you can launch a command prompt as well. If you want to move folders that are not in use, you can do it from within windows too.

Comment: Great, I was able to reformat E drive and break it from dynamic disk.  Now I'm wondering a way I could extend my C drive from disk 0 (dynamic still), to use the space available on E drive (disk 1) to install and run new programs.